# How can I create this SQL query that has to join four tables to allow me extract the data I need?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I want to do is a PHP script that gets all the products of a Joomla VirtueMart using PHP and mySQL. However my question has nothing to do about Joomla or PHP but I am in the need of a mySQL query.

Below you can find the tables and the fields that holds the data I need which are

**product_id, product_desc, product_full_image, product_name, product_price, category_name.**

To get the **product_price** you will need the **product_id** from `jos_vm_product` and match it with the **product_id** from `jos_vm_product_price` to get the **product_price**.

Every **product_id** has a **category_id** inside `jos_vm_product_category_xref`. So, when the **category_id** is found, you get the **category_name** from `jos_vm_category`.

This is difficult for me as I am not very familiar with SQL queries and I need your help on how to to join those tables, so it will allow me to echo the values I need.

Thank you.

**jos_vm_poduct**

```
product_id
product_desc
product_full_image
product_name
```

**jos_vm_product_price**

```
product_id
product_price
```

**jos_vm_product_category_xref**

```
product_id
category_id
```

**jos_vm_category**

```
category_id
categroy_name
```

Comment: delete jos_vm_product_price and jos_vm_product_category_xref, put a category_id and product_price field into jos_vm_product.

Comment: The structure has to stay as is. My question was not how to edit the DB but how to make use of it to get some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
SELECT jvp.product_id, product_desc, product_full_image, product_name, product_price, category_name   
FROM jos_vm_product jvp  
JOIN jos_vm_product_price jvpp  
ON jvp.product_id = jvpp.product_id  
JOIN jos_vm_product_category_xref jvpcx  
ON jvpcx.product_id = jvp.product_id  
JOIN jos_vm_category jvc  
ON jvc.category_id = jvpcx.category_id
```

Any questions about why, please ask away!

Answer (score 2):

Sure we could write you an answer, but, to best understand it heres the things you want to know

```
select <stuff> from <table1>
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

You then join it with another table

so,

```
select product_name, product_price from table1 
left join table2 on table1.product_id=table2.product_id
```

once you've linked your tables.

Now strip out the bits you either want, or dont want. Such as, if you left join.. you may want

```
where product_price>0
```

When you have then stripped or selected the bit(s) you wanted, job done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want all the products of a given category. If not it's easy to remove the where clause to grab them all.

I used a subquery to fetch all the product id's of a given category, then join the other two tables.

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            p.product_id,
            c.category_name, 
        FROM 
            jos_vm_product_category_xref AS p
            LEFT JOIN jos_vm_category AS c
            ON p.category_id == c.category_id
        WHERE 
            c.category_id = 4
        ) as products
        LEFT JOIN jos_product 
        ON jos_product.product_id=products.product_id
        LEFT JOIN jos_vm_product_price 
        ON jos_vm_product_price=products.product_id
```